# to transition vs. to transit

Tags: word-choice

To my knowledge, *transition* is (also) a rarely used intransitive verb. *To transit* seems a lot more common.

I'm trying to understand the difference between them.

Personally, *transit* seems mainly linked to transportation, while *transition* rather applies to a change in the state of being.

Comment: What you’ve written there sounds right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples to help you.

> I will be in **transit** when you get your test results.  Email me and I'll check my email as soon as my plane lands.
>
> The transition from elementary school to middle school [age 11 in the U.S.] is huge.  You go from being in one room all day long with the same teacher, to seven different teachers and classrooms.

That was to set the scene.  Now I'll express the same idea but with the verb *transition*.

> In our next edition of the newsletter, we will be giving you helpful tips on helping your child **transition** to middle school.

This verb is very common in the K-12 education context.